# Can I tell clang-format to not add space around arithmetic operators

Tags: clang-format

clang-format seems to always add spaces around operators. For example, the following:

```
a = b+c
```

becomes:

```
a = b + c
```

Is there a way to tell it not to add spaces around `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`?

I already know about [`SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) (as shown here), I am looking for something similar for operators.

Similar concerns (but with a different direction) in [How to add capabilities to clang-format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207030/how-to-add-capabilities-to-clang-format).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell clang-format to keep whitespace between binary operators as they are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259984/how-to-tell-clang-format-to-keep-whitespace-between-binary-operators-as-they-are)

Comment: @zukunft: Same question, but the issue still holds. :-/